# gl3w error from c++ file

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a project where I first build `gl3w.c` with gcc and then my own `OGLGraphics.cpp` file with g++.  Gcc successfully compiles `gl3w.c` but when g++ attempts to compile the file that includes `gl3w.h` I get these errors:

```
In file included from /mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/graphics/OGLGraphics.cpp:22:0:
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:69:8: error: ‘PFNGLDRAWARRAYSPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:70:8: error: ‘PFNGLDRAWELEMENTSPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:71:8: error: ‘PFNGLGETPOINTERVPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:72:8: error: ‘PFNGLPOLYGONOFFSETPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:73:8: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYTEXIMAGE1DPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:74:8: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYTEXIMAGE2DPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:75:8: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE1DPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:76:8: error: ‘PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE2DPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:77:8: error: ‘PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE1DPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:78:8: error: ‘PFNGLTEXSUBIMAGE2DPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:79:8: error: ‘PFNGLBINDTEXTUREPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:80:8: error: ‘PFNGLDELETETEXTURESPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:81:8: error: ‘PFNGLGENTEXTURESPROC’ does not name a type
/mnt/hgfs/grace/src/grace-output/include/GL3/gl3w.h:82:8: error: ‘PFNGLISTEXTUREPROC’ does not name a type
```

I don't know why it works with a C file but not from C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you follow the procedure as outlined in GL3W's readme file? Specifically, the part about including `gl3w.h` *first*, before any OpenGL files.

Oh, and before `window.h`, which can include `gl.h`.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern PFNGLDRAWARRAYSPROC gl3wDrawArrays;  <—— unknown type name PFNGLDRAWARRAYSPROC
```

This error is caused by the inclusion of `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>` in your code such as GLTriangleBatch.h. If you substitute #include "GL/gl3w.h” instead, which is OpenGL 3/4 calls, then this will remove the error.  I think that there is a conflict between different versions of OpenGL calls and this results in the unknown type error.  I ran into this same problem myself when I was trying to port SuperBible 5 code into SB6.